# Nameless function as function argument?

Tags: python, events

I am writing a python script involving an event listener. The basic idea is this:

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self,callback):
        self.callback = callback

    def call(self,data):
        self.callback(data)

    def check(self,data);
        #Do some logic to see if this event should be called
        return True #Or false

class Event_Handler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = []

    def process_input(self,data):
        for event in self.events:
            if event.check(data):
                event.call(data)

    def create_event(self,callback):
        event = Event(callback)
        self.events.append(event)

handler = Event_Handler()
```

I can now add events by:

```
def function_to_call(data):
    print('hello, this event just got called')
handler.create_event(function_to_call)
```

However, this would require naming each callback function. This of course is possible, but it does not seem necessary to me. Is it possible to use nameless functions in python in any way. So something like this:

```
handler.create_event(
    def(data):
        print('hello, this nameless event just got called')
)
```

I got this approach from javascript. Is this possible in python. And if so, are there any reasons why i should use it or not?

P.S. I know about `lambda`, but that is mainly aimed at small functions.

Comment: No, that's it - your two options are a `lambda`, limited to a single expression, or a regular function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe A single expression can run several statements: https://ideone.com/w6nIS3 :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to use nameless functions in python in any way. So something like this:
>
> ```
> handler.create_event(
>     def(data):
>         print('hello, this nameless event just got called')
> )
> ```

Unfortunately no. Python has only one syntactic construct for defining anonymous (or nameless) functions;  the `lambda` keyword. There are simply no other ways to create anonymous functions.

> I got this approach from javascript. Is this possible in python.

I'd advising against trying to draw exact feature parallels between languages. They rarely, if ever, exist. Simply put, if you want anonymous functions, use `lambda`.

As user2864740 stated:

> The def can be nested in a local scope so even if not "in-line" it doesn't need to be a 'method' or otherwise exposed if the handler is setup in an isolated context (ie. a function that initialize and returns the handler). OTOH, it may also be preferable to use/bind a method.

Comment: The `def` can be nested in a local scope so even if not "in-line" it doesn't need to be a 'method' or otherwise exposed if the handler is setup in an isolated context (ie. a function that initialize sand returns the handler). OTOH, it may also be preferable to use/bind a method..

Comment: @user2864740 True, those are good points. I'll add that to my answer.